# angular2 material table hide column

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following angular2 material table

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" >

        <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
              The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

        <!-- Position Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="selected">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="selectAll"></mat-checkbox>
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="element.selected" [checked]="selectAll"></mat-checkbox>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="requested_status">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.requested_status}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        ......
```

I need to hide a column in the table by some boolean condition. **Is it possible without changing columns map in my component?**

```
displayedColumns = ['selected', 'id', ...];
```

I tried to use `*ngIf` but it doesn't work. How to do that?

Comment: modify the displayedColumns according to requirment

Answer (score 39):

no need of any directives.

just use

> **[hidden]**
>   it will work
>   ex:[hidden]="show" in html
>   and 
>   set show to boolean in ts file.

my html code:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="department" >
  <mat-header-cell [hidden]="show" *matHeaderCellDef> 
    Department 
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell [hidden]="show" *matCellDef="let element">
    {{element.department}}
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 24):

The angular way to do this is to [update the columns passed to your row template](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9940):

**HTML:**

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: getDisplayedColumns();"></mat-row>
```

**TS:**

```
const columnDefinitions = [
  { def: 'col1', showMobile: true },
  { def: 'col2', showMobile: false },
];

getDisplayedColumns(): string[] {
  const isMobile = this.currentDisplay === 'mobile';
  return this.columnDefinitions
    .filter(cd => !isMobile || cd.showMobile)
    .map(cd => cd.def);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is if you are using a mat-menu checkbox, the dialog closes each time you click a check.  Only display = none solved the issue (with event.stopPropagation()).

Comment: another problem is that `getDisplayedColumns()` will be triggered with each change detection (which happens very often).

Comment: This is a minimal example to get the point across, both comments you guys make have easy fixes like not calling getDisplayedColumns() but a constant that is populated one time, or when x event occurs. Your points do not make this approach invalid, just adapt your implementations.

Comment: This doesn't work. Mat table is unable to dynamically update columns after the initial array of column names (`displayedColumns`) is rendered. For example, if you are fetching some data, and on initial page load `displayedColumns = ['a', 'b']`, then it will show `a` and `b` as the columns. When the fetched data resolves and you now want to dynamically change the columns to `displayedColumns=['a', 'b', 'c']`, thus adding column `c`, this will not work. The columns will not be dynamically updated, or at least not consistently. This is a problem.

Comment: This does work, work on your implementation instead of copy pasting a minimal working example.

Answer (score 15):

To the column you want to hide, add this:

```
[style.display]="'none'"
```

You should add to both the mat-heather-cell and the mat-cell.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using Angular Flex  Responsive API (https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API). 
Example:

```
     <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
        <th
          *matHeaderCellDef
          mat-header-cell
          mat-sort-header
          fxShow
          fxHide.lt-sm
        >
          Data
        </th>
        <td *matCellDef="let element" mat-cell fxShow fxHide.lt-sm>
          {{ element.date | date: "dd/MM/yyyy" }}
        </td>
        <td *matFooterCellDef mat-footer-cell fxShow fxHide.lt-sm>Total</td>
      </ng-container>
```

In this case, will hide in screen less than small (lt-sm).

Answer (score 5):

Finally i found a way to hide column without changing columns map.
We need to create an attribute directive, through this directive we can set the display property of an element.

ShowColumnDirective:

```
import {Component, Directive, ElementRef, Input, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
@Directive({ 
     selector: '[showCoulmn]' 
})
export class ShowColumnDirective implements AfterViewInit{
    @Input() showInput: string;
    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) { 
    }
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.style.display = this.showInput;
    }
}
```

Declare this directive in AppModule or any other module:

```
import {TableBasicExample} from './table-basic-example';
import {ShowColumnDirective} from './table-basic-example';
@NgModule({

  imports: [
    ..........
  ],

  declarations: [TableBasicExample, ShowColumnDirective],
  bootstrap: [TableBasicExample],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now we can use the directive inside our table's html Component:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
  <mat-header-cell showCoulmn showInput="none" *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell showCoulmn showInput="none"    *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Here is working template: https://plnkr.co/edit/Woyrb9Yx8b9KU3hv4RsZ?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

The only possible solution seems to change displayed columns in the component class

```
displayedColumns = ['selected', 'id', ...];
```

Answer (score 1):

For Example:

In HTML:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="show_hide_details()">
    <span *ngIf="showHideDetails== true">Hide Details</span>
    <span *ngIf="showHideDetails== false">Show Details</span>
</button>

<ng-container matColumnDef="Cost">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header
    [ngStyle]="{display: showHideDetails === true? 'table-cell' : 'none'}">{{'Cost' | translate}}</th>

    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngStyle]="{display: showHideDetails === true? 
     'table-cell' : 'none'}">{{element.cost}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

In TS:

```
showHideDetails: boolean = false;

show_hide_details() {
this.showHideDetails= !this.showHideDetails;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The responsiv way:**

*hope it still helps :)*

in TS:

```
styleUrls: ['style.component.scss'],
```

in style.component.scss:

```
  /* language=SCSS */
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 1280px) {
    .lg\:block {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }
}
```

in HTML:

```
  <table mat-table
         [dataSource]="dataSource">
   
    <th class="hidden lg:block"
        mat-header-cell
        *matHeaderCellDef>HEADER
    </th>

    <td class="hidden lg:block"
        mat-cell
        *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.data }} </td>

   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to hide a row by some changeable condition I suggest following way:

```
// css
.hidden-row {
  display: none;
}

// html
<ng-container matColumnDef="importDate">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [ngClass]="showColumn()">
      Date
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngClass]="showColumn()">
      {{element?.importDate}}
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

// ts
showColumn(): string {
  return this.someService.hasAccess() ? null : 'hidden-row';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution @John Smith didn't work form me. Instead I used this adjustment:

```
 // css
 .hidden-item {
   display: none;
 }

 // html
 <ng-container matColumnDef="importDate">
   <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [ngClass]="{'hidden-item': showColumn()}"> Date
   </mat-header-cell>
   <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngClass]="{'hidden-item': showColumn()}"> {{element?.importDate}}
   </mat-cell>
 </ng-container>

 // ts
 showColumn(): boolean {
   return this.someService.hasAccess();
 }
```

Comment: don't use functions in Angular templates. It triggers re-render on every change detection cycle

Comment: is there a problem with that ?

Comment: @ObumunemeNwabude Unless you're using Signals, yes

Answer (score 0):

It's possible as explained in this wrong issue: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8944

View:

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

class:

```
displayedColumns = ['tab1', 'tab2', 'tab3'];
```

but in constructor:

```
if (this.removeOneColumn) this.displayedColumns = ['tab1', 'tab3'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, where the user can display or hide columns through a checkbox. I solve my problem through a pipe, like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-dynamic-table",
  template: `
    <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let column of columns" [(ngModel)]="column.show">{{column.name | titlecase}}</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      ....
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns | toggleColumns:columns;"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns | toggleColumns:columns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
  `
})
export class DynamicTableComponent {
  private _columns = [
    {
      name: "date",
      show: true
    }, {
      name: "selected",
      show: true
    }, {
      name: "id",
      show: true
    }, {
      name: "location",
      show: true
    }
  ];

  get columns() { return this._columns; }
  get displayedColumns(): string[] { return this._columns.map(c => c.name); }
}

@Pipe({
  name: "toggleColumns"
})
export class ToggleColumnsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(displayedColumns: string[], columns): string[] {
    displayedColumns = columns.filter(c => !!c.show).map(c => c.name);
    return displayedColumns;
  }

}
```

Now you just need to manage to change the `show` attribute of the column from `true <=> false` so the column will be disappear if `show: false` and it will be displayed when `show: true`. I do that as you see with `mat-checkbox`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way which is writing some dirty code for both html and css codes, say, specify each column with an identifier then set a rule (like `display: none;`) to hide them when necessary. *Considering that a table will produced row by row, not column by column.*

**But the correct way is** the common & easiest way which is ***changing column map in component*** (for example, when an event fires).

Answer (score 0):

For my case, the below css code is not working.

```
display:none
```

Thanks to Rod Astrada, I try add the below code into **mat-header-cell** then working, then it works!

```
[style.display]="'none'"
```

like the following example:

```
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [style.display]="'none'">Id</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [style.display]="'none'"> {{element.id}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method For delete Or add column in mat-table.

```
columnsToDisplay: string[] = ['id', 'vcName', 'vcFamily', 'Phone']


  addOrRemoveTableColumn(colName: string, index: number) {

    if ( this.columnsToDisplay.filter(q => q.valueOf() == colName).length > 0) {
      this.columnsToDisplay = this.columnsToDisplay.filter(q => q.valueOf() != colName);
    }
    else if (this.columnsToDisplay.filter(q => q.valueOf() == colName).length == 0) {
      this.columnsToDisplay.splice(index, 0, colName);
    }
  }
```

For Example:

```
this.addOrRemoveTableColumn("id",6);
```