# Angular Column Visibility

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my code, I have a table that contains a couple of columns that I need the value of. I don't want the user to see those columns. How can I make them not visible? PS. I tried `Visible = false` but I was still able to see the whole column.

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ProductCategory">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Kategori</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
            <span *ngIf="EditIndex != i">{{row.ProductCategory?.CategoryName}}</span>
            <mat-form-field *ngIf="EditIndex == i" class="w-100-p" >
                <mat-select required name="ProductCategory" [(ngModel)]="row.ProductCategory"
                    (selectionChange)="productCategoryChange(row, $event.value.ProductCategoryId, i)">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let prm of productCategories" [value]="prm" >
                        {{prm.CategoryName}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular2 material table hide column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077302/angular2-material-table-hide-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Material already provides that feature. You can add this line inside your table:

```html
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
```

`displayedColumns` is an array of strings, that contains the matColumnDef-strings of the visible columns. Only the columns that are defined in the array will be visible. If you would want to show the column from your example the array would look like this:

```js
["ProductCategory"]
```

For more infos take a look at the documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/table/api